# Is the app name on a Push Notification in iOS 11 always all-caps?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I notice that the title on the notification is the app display name, forced to all caps.

The client's app name is a mix of upper and lower case that is part of their branding. They want the name to honor that mixed upper/lower case.

Does anybody know of a way to change the text that's displayed in the notification, or are we stuck with an upper-case version of the app display name?

[image: notification]

Comment: I don't think it is possible - yes application name in all the notifications are capital by default. I guess it is a design choice

Comment: Hey did you find out if this is possible?